# Alternatives for taking a screenshot

Tags: c#

I'm doing a bot to read images and transform it in text using Tesseract, but I have a problem with the target application named Tibia (Its a game in window mode screen), because it have a anti-screenshot protection. If I try, I got a black screen picture.

A already have try `CopyFromScreen()`, `user32.dll`, and `gdi.dll` functions but without success.

I tried these ways:

```
Bitmap printscreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen as Image);
graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, printscreen.Size);
```

And:

```
public static Bitmap GetDesktopImage()
{
    WIN32_API.SIZE size;

    IntPtr hDC = WIN32_API.GetDC(WIN32_API.GetDesktopWindow());
    IntPtr hMemDC = WIN32_API.CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);

    size.cx = WIN32_API.GetSystemMetrics(WIN32_API.SM_CXSCREEN);
    size.cy = WIN32_API.GetSystemMetrics(WIN32_API.SM_CYSCREEN);

    m_HBitmap = WIN32_API.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, size.cx, size.cy);

    if (m_HBitmap != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        IntPtr hOld = (IntPtr)WIN32_API.SelectObject(hMemDC, m_HBitmap);
        WIN32_API.BitBlt(hMemDC, 0, 0, size.cx, size.cy, hDC, 0, 0, WIN32_API.SRCCOPY);
        WIN32_API.SelectObject(hMemDC, hOld);
        WIN32_API.DeleteDC(hMemDC);
        WIN32_API.ReleaseDC(WIN32_API.GetDesktopWindow(), hDC);
        return System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(m_HBitmap);
    }
    return null;
}

public class WIN32_API
{
    public struct SIZE
    {
        public int cx;
        public int cy;
    }
    public const int SRCCOPY = 13369376;
    public const int SM_CXSCREEN = 0;
    public const int SM_CYSCREEN = 1;

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DeleteDC")]
    public static extern IntPtr DeleteDC(IntPtr hDc);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DeleteObject")]
    public static extern IntPtr DeleteObject(IntPtr hDc);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "BitBlt")]
    public static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hdcDest, int xDest, int yDest, int wDest, int hDest, IntPtr hdcSource, int xSrc, int ySrc, int RasterOp);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateCompatibleBitmap")]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleBitmap(IntPtr hdc, int nWidth, int nHeight);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateCompatibleDC")]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hdc);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "SelectObject")]
    public static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr bmp);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetDesktopWindow")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetDC")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr ptr);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetSystemMetrics")]
    public static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int abc);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowDC")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(Int32 ptr);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "ReleaseDC")]
    public static extern IntPtr ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDc);
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Have anyone api to capture print direct from GPU?

Comment: what is anti-screenshot protection? for the whole screen or just a window? what comes back black?

Comment: Idk what is his anti-screenshot protection. If i try, i got the black screen just in the application window.

Comment: did you try to run as admin? what application are you trying to capture?

Comment: I already try to run as admin, its really a screen shot protection due to prevent botting. Its one game named Tibia. That run in a window

Comment: [Desktop Duplication API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/desktop-dup-api)

Comment: @Jimi Can you give me a exemple using c#?

Comment: stackoverflow should not help on theft of copyrighted material.

Comment: @SQLPolice Edited, but why i got 2 down votes?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsui_team/2013/03/25/ways-to-capture-the-screen/

Comment: @KenWhite C# please :(

Comment: C# has nothing to do with it. Those are various ways that you can capture a screen in Windows. I'm not doing your research for you. The WinAPI is written with C in mind, and you'll find the majority of documentation for it uses C as the language for examples and function declarations. The link I provided discusses alternative options for doing what you ask. Make an effort to investigate them.

Comment: But i can use C# with a library .dll writen in C or C++ ?

Comment: I don't remember the exact details, but it's possible the game isn't using some kind of block and it is related to display overlays.  Usually a graphics driver will not render those in a screen shot and there is nothing at all you can do about it.

Comment: window mode screen? did you try snipping tools?

Comment: Snipping tools do not resolve for me

Comment: By design, it's difficult from Windows itself to go around protections that Windows itself offers. Check this (also the chat discussion): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56302217/prevent-desktop-sharing-of-a-particular-c-sharp-winforms-or-detect-desktop-shari The app developer may have simply used SetWindowDisplayAffinity. It also prevents the Desktop Duplication API to work I think.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the screenshot you need to go a layer lower than device contexts and Gdi. The game is not doing the rendering on the device context of the `hWnd` and instead talking to the graphic card driver. So when you call `CreateCompatibleBitmap` there is essentially nothing rendered there. I am not sure if there are any public APIs to capture what is being rendered directly. Some games do this because they would like to have faster rendering and would prefer to skip GDI or GDI+.

Comment: But i want an way to acess this layer and take screenshot :(

Answer (score 2):

**DISCLAIMER: I am not responsible in any way for anything that anyone does with any code shared or made accessible from this answer.**

I agree that the concept of screen capturing video games that feature any type of anti-cheat software is sketchy. The other side of that coin is that there could be any number of valid personal reasons to have a separate utility that can capture screenshots or video and process the content (i.e. custom notifications of in game activity, making the game more accessible to disabled persons by parsing messages and playing them through a synthesizer API, etc...).

All that being said, I downloaded and installed Tibia, copied the `FullScreenshot` code snippet from [this article](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/195/capturing-screenshots-of-different-ways-with-c-and-winforms) into a simple WinForms app project, and was able to save a screenshot of the game (shown below).

The WinForms app can be [downloaded from here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!At8HP2hlc5_wgb1OImucYQIzhv2WkA?e=37ruBo) to test before playing with the code yourself.

**Screenshot of Tibia from custom app:**
[image: this screenshot]

Comment: I agree with your all adversings @TroyPalacino. This way works only for 15 min. After that the window became to black pixels again.

Comment: Can you provide some more details? Do you mean after the game has been open for 15 minutes or taking screenshots for 15 minutes? How frequently does your app capture the screenshots?

Comment: After the game has been open for 15 minutes. I take screenshots every 400ms

Comment: does the entire screen capture go blank or just the game window? also, during those 15 minutes are you actively interacting with the with the game window or just allowing the game window to be idle?

Comment: Just the game window. allowing the game window to be idle

Comment: I suggest trying to interact with the window in some insignificant way programmatically ever couple of minutes. Perhaps move the mouse over the window and then off again or click on the title bar or something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205683/discussion-between-troy-palacino-and-victor-laio).